# Is it possible to integrate Spring Security in Spring application which uses AOP

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, spring-aop

In the existing application, we are using Spring AOP for transactions. Now we are asked to integrate Spring Security. When we tried integrating, we are getting multiple errors. Later we found that in this [link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/123003-spring-security3-iserasecredentialsafterauthentication-no-method-found-exception) that conflicts happen with Spring Security and Spring AOP, since Spring Security uses AOP internally.

Is it really possible to integrate Spring Security in Spring AOP application?

Comment: which spring version, what have you tried? Are you planning to integration spring security 3? (the link is from 2012..)

Comment: the existing application using Spring 3.0. We tried integrating Spring Security 3.0. and we got java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.isEraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication() error. We googled and came to know that its because of AOP. When removed AOP, it was working.

Comment: Spring Security leverages Spring AOP... If you get errors you have something weird.wrong in your setup.